# running Process Explorer as administrator at log on of non-admin account

Tags: windows, powershell, administrator, scheduled-tasks, process-explorer

I have tried to achieve a supposedly simple task of running Process Explorer with administrator rights (to show all processes) when logging on as normal user on my Win10 Pro 21H1 system. It proved to be more difficult than I anticipated.

#### Here is my situation:

1. I have several normal user accounts, let's say one of them called *johny_user*
2. I have one admin account, let's say called *johny_admin*

What I want is that when I log on as *johny_user*, I want to run Process Explorer with administrator privileges. Ideally, I would like to do without any manual intervention and avoid UAC prompt.

#### Task Scheduler method

At first, I wanted to create a task in task scheduler to do this, similarly to what is described here: [Run task manager (process explorer) as administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/654289/run-task-manager-process-explorer-as-administrator)

However, when I run task scheduler as *johny_user*, I cannot create a task to be run with highest privileges, providing *johny_admin* credentials. If I try to do it, I receive this error ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIIj0.png)):

```
Task Scheduler cannot create the task.
The user account is unknown, the password is incorrect,
or the user account does not have permission to create this task.
```

If I run Task Scheduler with *johny_admin* credentials, I can create the task without problems. I use these options:

- condition "Run at logon of johny_user"
- When running the task, use the following user account: johny_admin
- Security Option "Run when user is logged on"
- Run with highest privileges - checked

When I logon as *johny_user*, the Process Explorer is indeed run in *johny_admin* context, but with no GUI, thus beating the purpose of running it.

#### PowerShell Method

So I decided I should try running Process Explorer with Powershell script that would be launched by Task Scheduler at logon. I did not want to give password in plain text, so I went for this:

**script1.ps1**

```
$PassKey = get-content C:\scripts\passkey.txt
$Password = get-content C:\scripts\password.txt | Convertto-SecureString -Key $PassKey
$pp=New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "MY-PC\johny_admin",$Password

$script = "c:\scripts\script2.ps1"

Start-Process powershell -Credential $pp -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process $script -verb runas}'
```

And **script2.ps1** contains just:

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Process Explorer\procexp.exe" -ArgumentList "/t /p:h"
```

Script1.ps1 should run script2.ps1 with elevated permissions. However, even though a new powershell console appears for a moment, the script is not run.

#### Working, but...

So far, the only way I could achieve my goal was using AdvancedRun from Nirsoft. However, cfg file for this software needs to have *johny_admin's* password in plain text which I do not like.

#### Therefore

Can anyone advice how I could achieve this simple task?
I do not care much about whether I achieve it with Task Scheduler, Powershell or any other method. I just want to avoid storing admin credentials in plain text somewhere.

Some links that were useful for me when writing the Powershell scripts:
https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-elevate.html
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/132e170f-e3e8-4178-9454-e37bfccd39ea/startprocess-verb-runas-amp-credential?forum=winserverpowershell
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723583/how-to-launch-an-other-ps1-within-a-ps1-with-an-other-accompt-and-admin-rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is running a process that requires admin elevation without
specifying the password in plain-text.

One solution would be to use a utility such as
[RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html)
with which you may call a program, requiring a password.
The password and all other details are kept by RunAsSpc in an encrypted database.
It can do `runas` plus password plus encryption (although the user can be you yourself).

RunAsSpc is free for private use.
For more details about using it see the article
[Pass the password to Runas with RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/guidance.html).

For a simple protection against non-sophisticated users,
you might sprinkle references to undefined environmental variables
around your batch file. Such variables come up as empty when evaluated,
but they will dissuade reading the batch file.

Using this idea, the following script :

```
@echo off
echo "Hello, world!"
```

may look like this :

```
@%n%e%x%c%s%h%z%o%f% o%d%f%d%f
e%n%c%o%h%n%o %n%H%p%e%n%l%o%l%o%o%o%,%o% w%c%o%n%r%p%l%k%d%e%!%s%
```

Comment: I did not know about this software. Seems an interesting solution. I will definitely give it a try when I have little time and let you know. Thank you for now.

Comment: So I was able to solve it using RunAsRob application. This enables me to bypass UAC completely. It took a while until I was able to figure it out but now is all set and running. There is just an annoying popup window of the free version which appears randomly. I hoped I would be able to do it using common tools like PowerShell, but this is next best thing. Thank you for pointing me to this solution.